# PHP Hierarchical Navigational OOP structure

Tags: php, oop, navigation, hierarchy

What is the best way to represent a tree navigation structure using PHP? I need to be able to track the current page location in the tree using a bread crumb trail. Parts of the tree are generated from a database such as make -> models. Each model then has the same equivalent tree branch, such as:

Make > Model > (Area 1, Area 2, Area 3).

Parts of the tree may change over time. Is it best to have a static class hierarchy structure or a dynamic solution where classes are re-used?

Hope this has been explained simply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

- a `$nodes` list for each element [if empty it's a leaf node of course];
- a `$parent` field for parent element [if null it's the root node].

This way you can rebuild the breadcrumb trail for every node, providing them a `getTrail()` method:

```
public function getTrail()
{

    $parent = $this -> parent();

    $trail = array();

    while($parent !== NULL)
    {

        // push parent element to trail
        $trail[] = $parent;

        // go backwards one node
        $parent = $parent -> parent();

    }

    // you want trail in reverse order [from root to latest]
    return array_reverse($trail);

}
```

If your nodes differ in type, be clean providing a `TrailTrackable` interface with `getTrail()` / `getParent()` methods at least.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but how would I go about representing the actual data structure in an OOP respective? At the moment I am trying with MVC although it's proving relatively difficult. Essentially, all leaf's are a type of page1, page2, page3. Essentially, I don't want the page structure to be represented using a tree of inheritance but more of a re-usable set of classes. Do you understand where I'm going with this? Could I define the page types, extending a parent, use a factory pattern to determing which child to call and then resolve the tree? Hope you're getting this. Thanks!

Comment: More or less - you just write your classes [with all the fields you need], then provide the ones you want nodes and parent stuff eventually. Do no throw in MVC yet, we're still in the model :))

Comment: So these classes you're detailing would be essentially the fixed leaf types I defined earlier? TBH, if i just had a factory pattern calling the relevant leaf class based on what's stored in the database for that leaf, resolved the current trail passing them into an array as I looped. Essentially, I could call a single module (index.php?module=whatever&id=#), the database could associate the module (leaf) to a class type which the factoy pattern could build?

Answer (score 0):

```
class TreeNode {
    /**
 * the parent node
 *
 * @var TreeNode
 */
    private $parentNode=null;
     /**
 * the children of this node
 *
 * @var TreeNode[]
 */
    private $children=array();
     /**
 * The user element this tree node holds.
 *
 * @var Object
 */
    private $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing this solution would be essentially nested TreeNodes? Are you suggesting $element will hold a reference to the intended class (page_type_1, page_type_2, page_type_3) i wish to use for whatever functionality I intend to perform? If I was to make only leaf's act as a "page", could I basically assign an element where no children exist?

Comment: Yes, nested TreeNode instances. And yes, element would reference whichever type you intend to attach to it. And yes, nodes without children (0==count($this->children)) are by definition leaf nodes. Nodes without a parent node are root nodes. And to get the path to the root node (trail) you'd just just recurse until null==$parentNode and add the visited nodes to a stack.

Answer (score 0):

From an OO point of view, I'd recommend defining an interface such as the following:

```
interface BreadcrumbInterface
{
    public function getLabel();

    public function getParent(); // returns an instance of BreadcrumbInterface, or null
}
```

Then you'd create a Page class, which implements this interface and can optionally contain a 'parent', which must also implement this interface. This will build the heirarchy that you need.

A great way to retrieve the full breadcrumbs (while brushing up on your OO design patterns in the process) is to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#PHP_Example). In this case, you probably want to define a common abstract class as well as the interface in order to 'abstract away' the logic of handling the visitor...

```
abstract class BaseNode implements BreadcrumbInterface
{
    protected $parent = null;

    public function accept(BreadcrumbVisitor $visitor)
    {
        $visitor->visit($this);
    }

    public function setParent(BreadcrumbInterface $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
}

class BreadcrumbVisitor
{
    protected $breadcrumbs = array();

    public function visit(BreadcrumbInterface $node)
    {
        $parent = $node->getParent();
        if ($parent instanceof BaseNode) {
            $parent->accept($this);
        }

        $this->breadcrumbs[] = $node->getLabel();
    }

    public function getBreadcrumbs()
    {
        return $this->breadcrumbs;
    }
}
```

This won't run as is, but hopefully you get the idea. You probably also want your nodes to determine the URL to their page as well as the label, but that can be added easily enough. I just wanted to show the general OO structure to solving this problem.

**Edit:**

Adding rough usage example:

```
$rootPage = new Page(/*...*/);

$parentPage = new Page(/*...*/);
$parentPage->setParent($rootPage); // In reality you most likely wouldn't be building this structure so explicitly. Each object only needs to know about it's direct parent

$currentPage = new Page(/*...*/);
$currentPage->setParent($parentPage);

$visitor = new BreadcrumbVisitor();
$currentPage->accept($visitor);
$breadcrumbs = $visitor->getBreadcrumbs(); // returns an array, where the first element is the root

// then you can implode with ' > ' if you want
$breadcumbString = implode(' > ', $breadcrumbs);
```

Comment: Would you suggest extending the page class with the classes providing the relevant functionality such as page -> pageType1, pageType2, pageType3? Also, would I create this hierarchy as i resolve the trail to the current leaf?

Comment: I don't see why you'd need classes for each page. They'd most likely be different instances of the Page class. But yes, feel free to extend the Page class if you need to add functionality.

Comment: Well, as much as they would all be of type Page, one may be to perform one type of specific functionality, another would perform another type of functionality common across the website, a bit like Media > Image, Video, Music

Comment: Oh and by the way, I deliberately didn't call the base class 'BasePage' because this could very well be something like a 'Section', but it would still have the same 'breadcrumby' behavior.

Comment: What you do in your pages is up to you, but it sounds as though it's getting outside the context of this question.

Comment: Ye, I get what you're saying. What would I do with regards to a page having a consistant wrapper, placing this in the parent Page class? Also, With this type of design pattern, what would your suggestion to presentation / Logic placement be?

Comment: The presentation logic would be somewhere else entirely. This object only represents the 'M' in the [MVC pattern](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/). Your presentation layer (e.g. a controller) would be in charge of fetching these objects and passing them to a view, whether that be a template file or just plain PHP.

Comment: So you can implement this in a MVC style then, sounds quite logical to be honest. Finally (I hope), will I have to create a new BreadcrumbVisitor and accept it for each parent in the hierarchy?

Comment: Nope. With the hierarchy in place (where each page knows about only it's parent) you need only pass the one visitor into the current page, which will be the 'leaf node' of the tree, and then the visitor will contain the breadcrumbs for however many parents there are until the root of the tree is reached.

Comment: Sorry about this. Will I have to create a class for each page in the hierarchy then?

Comment: Nope. I've updated the example to show what I meant in my first comment. Each page is the same class, but a different instance. It doesn't matter if any of these instances are of a class that extends Page and provides extra functionality. That's all I can say for now.

Comment: Sorry, "New Class" was bad terminology. I did mean new instantiation. Thanks for that anyway, I'm sure I can crack on with something here. Thanks!